# mint update failed to fetch ppa 404 not found

Tags: node.js, linux-mint

I'm on mint 17.1 Rebecca Cinammon 64.

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I recieve the following error.

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources    
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Fetched 607 kB in 2s (222 kB/s)               
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/richarvey/nodejs/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/richarvey/nodejs/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/richarvey/nodejs/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I looked around the internet and it seems to be an issue with my PPA

I changed the "Base (Trusty)" Official repository from the default, one that was in the UK, to a closer one.

In `/etc/apt/sources.list` I have:

```
#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 17.1 _Rebecca_ - Release amd64 20141126]/ trusty contrib main non-free
```

And my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/richarvey-nodejs-trusty.list` looks like

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/richarvey/nodejs/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/richarvey/nodejs/ubuntu trusty main
```

Any help would be appreciated if you need more info let me know. I want to update my computer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because http://forums.linuxmint.com is probably a better place for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently running the same OS (Mint 17.1, Cinnamon) and followed the instructions [here](https://nodesource.com/blog/nodejs-v012-iojs-and-the-nodesource-linux-repositories) to install Node.js. Note, I came across this website while reading installation instructions on Joynet's GitHub [page](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager).

I'm wondering if that PPA is no longer updated (last update was almost two years ago)? I would remove this PPA by following instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed), removing your current `node` binary and follow the instructions above.